# Facebook page admins with graph api 2.0

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I had some code that was working perfectly before facebook upgraded to the graph api 2.0 on 4.30.15.  Since then only one admin on a page with multiple admins is recognized via the following code:

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => '##########',
  'secret' => '########',
  'fileUpload' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
   $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => ($user['baseurl'].'logout.php') ));
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_pages , manage_pages'));
}

if ($user) {
      echo '<div class="login"><a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout</a></div>';
}
else {
    echo '<div class="login">
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
     <a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login with Facebook</a>
     </div>';
}
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$params = array('access_token' => $access_token);

if ($user) {
$accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts', 'GET', $params);

foreach($accounts['data'] as $account) {
    echo '<br />'.$account['name'].' '.$account['access_token'];
}}
?>
```

Echoing $account['name'].' '.$account['access_token'] gives the page name and access token as expected for one admin but not for any of the others... any ideas as to why?

Comment: Did the other page admins grant `manage_pages` permission to your app? Did they even get asked for it? And if they are not admins (/developer/testers) of the app as well, did you get the permission reviewed and approved?

Comment: You nailed it... they are not admins and the permission wasn't reviewed and approved.  Thanks!